# How to do memcached sessions with django 1.8

Tags: python, django, memcached

In my django 1.6 app I did the following to get cached sessions and I'm curious if any of this has changed for django 1.8. The goal here is 100% in memory sessions so a restart will wipe the slate clean / that each web request will require 1 less database query / that it could scale many frontend machines if I need to share this session across a load balancer (also assuming 1.8 still passes the CSRF token in the cookie ... this should work across a farm of servers)

First I would add a requirement to the txt file like so

```
python-memcached==1.54
```

Next in my settings file I'd do the following

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    },
}

CACHE_BACKEND = 'caching.backends.memcached://localhost:11211'
```

Has anything changed? Could I add anything to improve this based on the requirements I listed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings have remained the same; TEMPLATE and urls.py are the major changes. Documentation is here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/

As for the package to use in requirements.txt, it can depend on whether or not you are using Python 2 or 3. Naturally, the memory question is far beyond the scope of Django and depends on (1) how much you're putting in the cache and its settings; (2) how much memory you have.